# How to put an object on amazon S3 using the SOAP API on windows phone 7?

Tags: soap, windows-phone-7, wsdl, amazon-s3

I'm having a hard time consuming the S3 API on Windows phone 7, mainly because of the lack of example for actually putting an object on S3 using the SOAP API?

Where do you even put the body of the item? As far as I know, there isn't even a field for it in the putObject method...

```
(PutObjectAsync(string Bucket, string Key, MetadataEntry[] Metadata, long ContentLength, Grant[] AccessControlList, Exam_Helper.AWS.StorageClass StorageClass, string AWSAccessKeyId, System.DateTime Timestamp, string Signature, string Credential, object userState))
```

So, how do you put an object on S3 with windows phone 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not recommend accessing the S3 API (or the Azure Storage API) direct from your phone.

If you try this, then you will need to either have public PUT permissions or you will have your private storage access keys in plain view in the XAP file - it will be **easy** for a hacker to steal these and you will soon be paying to host PimpMyBreasts, WikiL33ked and SpamThis.

Instead, you should host your own storage service where you can at least put some security checks in about what is being uploaded.

If you do insist on using S3 directly, then this article covers S3 from C# including PutObject requests - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/s3_ec2studio.aspx

Good luck

Stuart

Comment: Never quite looked at it this way, but you do make sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing that I've quite liked is that some apps have started using DropBox for their storage - this means the user has to provide their DropBox credentials - which might put some users off - but it's a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you added a service reference to the Amazon service in your project:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/AmazonS3.wsdl

Once added as a service reference, you can invoke `AmazonS3Client.PutObjectInlineAsync` to upload an object in a S3 bucket. The `Data` parameter (accepts a `byte` array) is what you're looking for.

Recommended reading:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/05/access-amazon-s3-services-with-silverlight-2.aspx